# Differential equations using Laplace transforms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

> By using Laplace transforms find $x(t)$ from the coupled differential equations$$\frac{dx}{dt} = -kx+gy+E,$$$$\frac{dy}{dt} = -ky-gx,$$for some functions $x(t),$ and $y(t)$, where $E, k, g$ are real. And we have the condition $x(t) = y(t) = 0$ for $t \leq 0.$

**Attempt:**

I know that the solution must be:

$$x(t)=\frac{Ek}{k^2+g^2} \Big[ 1+ e^{-kt} \Big[ -\cos(gt)+ \frac{g}{k} \sin(gt) \Big] \Big]. \tag{1}$$

I am trying to arrive at equation (1). Do I need to be considering the steady-state of the system? If so, when I set the two equations to zero, how can I take the Laplace transform of both sides? Because we do not have an explicit expression given for the functions $x(t)$ and $y(t).$

Also we don't know if the Laplace transforms of $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are convergent in the region $Real (s) > 0.$

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to consider steady-state of the system, simply take the Laplace transform of the coupled ODEs and solve for $X(s)$, where $X(s)$ is the Laplace transform of $x(t)$.

Comment: Also note that you  have defined the starting conditions and derivatives so there are no alternate solutions to the evolution from then on.  e.e you are evolving the condition x,y=0,0 and dx/dt=E at t=0 so it's all smooth sailing; so to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the Laplace transform of $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ by $X(s)$ and $Y(s)$. Taking Laplace transform of the coupled ODEs yields the following:
\begin{align}
sX & = -kX + gY + \dfrac{E}{s} \tag{1}\\
sY & = -kY - gX \tag{2}
\end{align}
where we use the assumption that we have zero initial conditions. Rearranging (2) to get an expression for $Y(s)$:
\begin{align*}
(s+k)Y & = -gX\\
\implies Y & = -\dfrac{gX}{s+k}\\
\end{align*}
Substituting this expression into (1) gives:
\begin{align*}
sX + kX & = g\left(-\dfrac{gX}{s+k}\right) + \dfrac{E}{s}\\
\left(s+k+\dfrac{g^2}{s+k}\right)X & = \dfrac{E}{s}\\
\left(\dfrac{(s+k)^2+g^2}{s+k}\right)X & = \dfrac{E}{s}\\
X(s) & = \dfrac{E(s+k)}{s[(s+k)^2+g^2]}\\
& = E\left(\dfrac{A}{s} + \dfrac{Bs+C}{(s+k)^2+g^2}\right)\\
& = EA\left\{\dfrac{1}{s}\right\} + EB\left\{\dfrac{s+k}{(s+k)^2+g^2}\right\} + \dfrac{E(C-Bk)}{g}\left\{\dfrac{g}{(s+k)^2+g^2}\right\}
\end{align*}
where
\begin{equation}
A = \dfrac{k}{k^2+g^2},\quad B = -\dfrac{k}{k^2+g^2},\quad C = \dfrac{g^2-k^2}{k^2+g^2}
\end{equation}
You should be able to figure out how to invert them; the frequency shifting theorem will be helpful.

Comment: I have arranged them in such a way that when you invert them accordingly you get exactly the expression that you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. But how do we know that the Laplace transforms $X(s)$ and $Y(s)$ are absolutely convergent in the region $>0$?

Comment: Not necessarily. $1/s$ is convergent for all $\Re(s)>0$, but the other two terms are convergent only for all $\Re(s)>-k$. So in order for $X(s)$ to converge in the region you wanted, $k$ should be a nonnegative real number. You can refer to wikipedia about the convergence region for different function here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms

Comment: What about for $Y(t)$? If we do not have the explicit expressions for $x(t)$ and $y(t),$ is it somehow possible to judge the convergence simply from the form of these DE equations, or by considering the steady state of this system?

Comment: Well we know that $Y(s)=-gX/(s+k)$, so partial fraction decomposition will give us an extra term $D/s+k$, and this term converges for $\Re(s)>-k$. I don't think knowing the equilibrium solution of the system will tell us anything about the region of convergence in the Laplace space; I might be wrong but as far as I know, it seems like we can only tell the region of convergence when we have an explicit form of solution  (either $x(t)$ or $X(s)$). Recall that we derive the region of convergence of $X(s)$ directly from the definition of Laplace transform.

Comment: Thank you, it makes perfect sense now. Here's my last question: if by the frequency shifting property you mean $L \Big[ e^{at} f(t) \Big] \leftrightarrow F(s-a),$ how does that exactly apply to the last expression for $X(s)$ in your answer? I thought you need to use the the complex inversion formula, or something like that to make the inversion and obtain the right expression for $x(t)$.

Comment: That was the right property. Since $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{F(s)\} = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\dfrac{g}{s^2+g^2}\right\}=\sin(gt)$, we have that (from frequency shifting property) $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{F(s+k)\} = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\dfrac{g}{(s+k)^2+g^2}\right\} = e^{-kt}\sin(gt)$. Note I didn't check the constants but you should be able to figure them out. Glad I can help (: